# Property annotations introspecting in Groovy

Tags: groovy

is there a convenient way to iterate Object's properties and to check annotations for each?

Comment: I don't think there is. Maybe you can give us more information on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
// First, declare your annotation
import java.lang.annotation.*

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface MyAnnot {
}

// Then, define your class with it's annotated Fields
class MyClass {
  @MyAnnot String fielda
  String fieldb
  @MyAnnot String fieldc
}

// Then, we will write a method to take an object and an annotation class
// And we will return all properties of the object that define that annotation
def findAllPropertiesForClassWithAnotation( obj, annotClass ) {
  obj.properties.findAll { prop ->
    obj.getClass().declaredFields.find { 
      it.name == prop.key && annotClass in it.declaredAnnotations*.annotationType()
    }
  }
}

// Then, define an instance of our class
MyClass a = new MyClass( fielda:'tim', fieldb:'yates', fieldc:'stackoverflow' )

// And print the results of calling our method
println findAllPropertiesForClassWithAnotation( a, MyAnnot )
```

In this instance,this prints out:

```
[fielda:tim, fieldc:stackoverflow]
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks, this was useful! not that super-elegant I could expect from Groovy, but it works :)

Comment: @pavlo inelegant compared to the java version of the same thing?

Comment: Using Groovy 2.4.5, this seems to be the way to do it :

`
def findAllPropertiesForClassWithAnotation( obj, annotClass ) {
  obj.properties.findAll { prop ->
    obj.class.declaredFields.find { field ->
      field.name == prop.key && field.declaredAnnotations*.annotationType().contains(annotClass)
    }
  }
}
`

Comment: Using `class.declaredFields` will cause problems if the properties are defined in a super class and properties added via `traits` will have names that you might not expect that definitely don't match the property name without manipulation.