# Best practices for domain object's string field auto trimming

Tags: string, grails, normalization

I need to normalize **some** String properties from my domain object, so I am looking for some best practices to do that in generic way.

```
class User {
   String name
   String email
   String password
   Integer age
   Date dateCreated

   static constraints = {
//        some constraints
   }
}
```

Let's say I want to remove all the trailing and leading spaces from `name` property that comes from user side or convert `email` string value to be in all lower case and remove all the spaces.

In future there will be other properties from other domain objects that need to be normalized as well. So I don't want to create a *static factory method* for this functionality and call it in every controller where I receive appropriate properties from client side. Would `Annotation` help me in this case?

I am using Grails 2.2.4.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to set Setters not necessarily getters.

```
class User {
    String name
    String email
    String password
    Integer age
    Date dateCreated

    void setName(String n) { 
     name=n.trim()
    }

    void setEmail(String e) { 
     email=e.toLowerCase()
    }

}
```

so as the entries come in they hit your setName, just remember in Java a pojo you manually set the set/get entries. In grails pogo all of this is generated for you but masked away for you to later use as required in your case trim/lowerCase.

I recently did some data transformation using getter/setter,

can be [seen here](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-wschat-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/grails/plugin/wschat/beans/CustomerChatTagBean.groovy#L32-L35).

This is not a domainClass and actual object type is JSON.

It takes input from the user [set as map](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-wschat-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/grails/plugin/wschat/beans/CustomerChatTagBean.groovy#L76-L90) so imagine this being what the end from is collecting and finally sending to the domainClass the object type as. The setter in that map link takes in the map and converts the data type to JSON

Now when I wish to represent that JSON information the javascripts are expecting a string value, (a json string to be precise)

So the  getter is now returning the result from json to String [get actual JSON and show String](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-wschat-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/grails/plugin/wschat/beans/CustomerChatTagBean.groovy#L92-L103)

Using set to convert input and get to convert db output to desired output.

Comment: +1 This is the correct way to address the issue. Combine this with a static utility class/method to do whatever cleaning is needed and you have the best solution. Why is it the best (in my opinion)? Because it's very clear and explicit about what the intention of each property on the class is. It's readable by the most novice of programmers and follows a very well known and used pattern. It does require you to author code, but that's part of doing things right. Not everything is going to be a magical annotation/single line/config solution.

Comment: Don't you think that setter is called from many places and it is always going to be applied, also when the domain object is loaded from the DB ?

Comment: when loaded from the DB to be represented for a view you then use the getters I have expanded above answers example further hopefully it will make more sense.

Comment: @vahid in case of `load` it also hits setter method, you can check it :)

Comment: When grails does its conversions it will add default getters/setters.... So their always their regardless of if you are setting them or not?  Please refer to Burt's Bible "Programming Grails" https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=nLqyHl_KfTQC&pg=PA5&lpg=PA5&dq=grails+pogo+getter/setter+burt&source=bl&ots=UBu5tYQORV&sig=ZdzFdNRjU_2j72s7diGd1Wh30zw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-yOz5tanJAhXGtRQKHTj6DAUQ6AEINDAD#v=onepage&q=grails%20pogo%20getter%2Fsetter%20burt&f=false  this will hopefully make more sense than me

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oxwpqh1h0s0 watch this video around minute 48 which Burt talks about transient elements and groovy compiler will create set/get for this element.... Its a good video to watch

Answer (score 2):

You can use "[Data Binding Event Listeners](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/single.html)"
The DataBindingListener interface provides a mechanism for listeners to be notified of data binding events.The interface looks like this:

```
package org.grails.databinding.events;
import org.grails.databinding.errors.BindingError;

public interface DataBindingListener {

/**
 * @return true if the listener is interested in events for the specified type.
 */
boolean supports(Class<?> clazz);

/**
 * Called when data binding is about to start.
 * 
 * @param target The object data binding is being imposed upon
 * @param errors the Spring Errors instance (a org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)
 * @return true if data binding should continue
 */
Boolean beforeBinding(Object target, Object errors);

/**
 * Called when data binding is about to imposed on a property
 *
 * @param target The object data binding is being imposed upon
 * @param propertyName The name of the property being bound to
 * @param value The value of the property being bound
 * @param errors the Spring Errors instance (a org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)
 * @return true if data binding should continue, otherwise return false
 */
Boolean beforeBinding(Object target, String propertyName, Object value, Object errors);

/**
 * Called after data binding has been imposed on a property
 *
 * @param target The object data binding is being imposed upon
 * @param propertyName The name of the property that was bound to
 * @param errors the Spring Errors instance (a org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)
 */
void afterBinding(Object target, String propertyName, Object errors);

/**
 * Called after data binding has finished.
 *  
 * @param target The object data binding is being imposed upon
 * @param errors the Spring Errors instance (a org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)
 */
void afterBinding(Object target, Object errors);

/**
 * Called when an error occurs binding to a property
 * @param error encapsulates information about the binding error
 * @param errors the Spring Errors instance (a org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)
 * @see BindingError
 */
void bindingError(BindingError error, Object errors);}
```

Comment: As far as I know this one is not available for `grails 2.2.4`

Answer (score 2):

Using annotations to decorate fields and traits to decorate the classes:

I created 2 annotations to show 2 possibilities; a static normalization and something more dynamic using a closure in the annotation.

**Annotations**

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Normalize {
    Class value()
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface LowerCase {    
}
```

**Trait**
Adds a `beforeInsert` and `beforeUpdate` to illustrate both annotations.

```
trait Normalizer {
    def beforeInsert() {
        def props = AnnotationHelper.findAllPropertiesForClassWithAnotation(this, LowerCase)

        props.each{ prop ->
            this[prop.key] = prop.value.toLowerCase()
        }
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        def props = AnnotationHelper.findAllPropertiesForClassWithAnotation(this, Normalize)

        props.each { prop ->
            this[prop.key] = AnnotationHelper.getNormalizedValue(this, prop.key)
        }
    }
}
```

**Helper Class**
The `findAllPropertiesForClassWithAnotation` method was taken directly form an answer by @tim_yates ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389142/property-annotations-introspecting-in-groovy))

```
class AnnotationHelper {
    public static def findAllPropertiesForClassWithAnotation( obj, annotClass ) {
        obj.properties.findAll { prop ->
            obj.getClass().declaredFields.find { field ->
                field.name == prop.key && annotClass in field.declaredAnnotations*.annotationType()
            }
        }
    }

    public static def getNormalizedValue( obj, fieldName ) {
        def matchingField = obj.getClass().declaredFields.find { it.name == fieldName }
        def normAnnotation = matchingField.declaredAnnotations.find{ it.annotationType() == Normalize }

        def normAnnotationValue = normAnnotation.value()
        def closure = normAnnotationValue.newInstance(null, null)
        matchingField.setAccessible(true)
        return closure.call(matchingField.get(obj))
    }
}
```

**Decorating your class**

```
class User implements Normalizer {
   @LowerCase
   String name

   @Normalize({ it -> it.toUpperCase() })
   String email
   String password
   Integer age
   Date dateCreated
}
```

Depending on what groovy version you are using, traits may not be applicable and you may need to just use an abstract class and inheritance instead.
This is not 'battle-tested' in any way, and I changed your original trimming normalization to make it easier to test but hopefully you can see what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it is best practice but I would use [GORM events](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.2.x/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping) to do that kind of individual property normalization.

It depends on your use case which event you choose.

Here an example of setting `email` to lower case before inserting into the database.

```
class User {
    String name
    String email
    String password
    Integer age
    Date dateCreated

    def beforeInsert() {
        email = email.toLowerCase()
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that this is a good idea, because I need also `beforeUpdate` and I might have many domain classes, so I need to write specific `beforeUpdate` and `beforeInsert` for every domain...

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can implement the `beforeUpdate()` and `beforeInsert()` domain class methods to sanitize the input. But from a best practice perspective this is not a good idea because a domain class should be concerned with persistence and unit of work (*selfish*) business logic, not sanitizing its input.

The data should be sanitized close to where they are introduced: the controller. (No, that was not grammatical mistake; data is plural)

This doesn't mean that it has to be done within the controller itself. The controller can defer to another object. In fact, my recommendation is to take a Grails like approach.

1. Declare the sanitation rules within the domain class in a static Closure using a custom dsl.
2. Implement the dsl.
3. Use the dsl from the controller prior to saving the domain class instance.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to have something tightly connected with specific domain class, because in case of multiple domain classes it will suck. In that case I need to add that `closure` for every domain.

Comment: You misunderstood my suggestion. It would work like the Grails contraints closure which **declares** what you want. A secondary object, a reusable implementation, does the heavy lifting. You can't avoid adding *some* code to all affected domain classes. Unless you use a specify property naming convention which you can use to detect which properties to manipulate and how to manipulate them. That could get ugly.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding if you want to do it during databinding it can be done using configurations like:

```
grails.databinding.convertEmptyStringsToNull=false
grails.databinding.trimStrings=false
```

@BindUsing with Closure parameter can also be used for these kind of changes.

http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-2-3-Data-Binding-String-Trimming-And-Null-Conversions-td4645255.html